# How to echo hash symbol (#) in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that creates an email template, in the template there is a link which contains a URL with a hash symbol (#) to anchor to a certain part of a page.

No matter how I do it, I cannot echo #, it will always convert to %23.

The relevant section of code,

```
$liURL = 'https://website.com/#hashed-section/#secondary-hash';
echo '<a href="'.$liURL.'">Link</a>';
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: no code provided

Comment: just escape it with a backslash: `$liURL = 'https://website.com/\#hashed-section/\#secondary-hash';`.

Comment: It must have something to do with the `/` before `#seconary-hash` because that echos, `https://website.com//#hashed-section/%5C%23secondary-hash`

Comment: Well, i guess there is only one `#` allowed, isn't it? Thatmmight cause the conversion from `#` to `%5C%23%`.

Comment: unless its a browser specific thing, i tried his code modified with double quotes around it in firefox and chrome, and cannot get it to output %5c%23 in any way

Comment: I tried firefox, chrome, safari.. then I ran a VM and it outputs correctly - not sure how it would be related to my machine but it appears to be.. ? .. I'm confused. Sorry to waste all your time, thanks for helping to clarify that.

Comment: I don't see why this is getting so many downvotes, I've been forced to upvote

Comment: Probably because I didn't post my code at first, but it was happening even if I simply executed `echo "#";` so I figured it was a common issue I couldn't find info on, turns out it's something related to my machine specifically. Looking into that now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html entity:

```
&num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if the structure, string function, and backslash before sign #.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape it with a backslash:

```
$liURL = 'https://website.com/\#hashed-section/\#secondary-hash';
```

Answer (score 0):

put it in double quotes

```
$liURL = "https://website.com/#hashed-section/#secondary-hash";
```

it will be treated as literal text then

Comment: sorry no way echo "https://website.com/#hashed-section/#secondary-hash"; will put %5C%23 in the output, unless you are running some other function on it you are not telling us about

Comment: You can run just this and it will put that in the output,
`<?php
$liURL = "https://website.com/#hashed-section/#secondary-hash";
echo '<a href="'.$liURL.'">Link</a>';`

Comment: lol - i did, here is the output from view code in chrome latest version 
<a href="https://website.com/#hashed-section/#secondary-hash">Link</a>

Comment: which is what I assume you were going for

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be the case, but I ran a VM and it outputs as it should.. Correctly. It must be something with the machine i'm using.

Comment: right, that is my thinking, it is something on your machine, but yes make sure you change to double quotes and it should solve your problem, also you may be loading a cached version, you may want to try clearing your cache and trying again

Answer (score 0):

If the same code works on other environments, it looks like it's a matter of settings, likely this:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

check your **php.ini** charset on the ones which work as you expect and then check and adjust the one which isn't working.